# How do you use global Coffeescript variables on client startup in Meteor?

Tags: coffeescript, meteor

In `lib.coffee` I have `@x = 1`. In `client.coffee` I have `Meteor.subscribe('data', x)`. When the page loads, I get the error in the console:

`Uncaught ReferenceError: x is not defined`

However, after the page has finished loading, and I type `x` in the console, it is recognized as a global variable with value 1.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It has to do with the order in which the source files are evaluated. For all the details, have a careful read of [this](http://docs.meteor.com/#structuringyourapp) section of the docs. You can play a number of games with file names and locations in order to change their load order:

- change the file names so they appear in alphabetical order
- put the files that need to be loaded first in a subdirectory
- put the files that need to be loaded first in a `lib` directory

In this particular case, however, you can just delay the activation of the subscription, by doing something like:

```
Meteor.startup ->
  Meteor.subscribe 'data', x
```

or

```
Tracker.autorun ->
  if Meteor.userId()
    Meteor.subscribe 'data', x
```

Tricks like these can be used to execute code after all of the source files has been evaluated.

Comment: Thanks a lot David for answering the majority of my SO meteor questions :) I was wondering why you don't upvote the questions - is it because they are not well formed or unlikely to be applicable to others?

Comment: Sure no problem. :) That's a good question... I probably should be more generous with the votes since I expect the same in return. +1